# ExtJS grid selectionchange data

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs4, selectionchanged

I have this code:

```
grid.getSelectionModel().on('selectionchange', function(selModel, selections) {}
```

and inside the function with the variable 'selections' I want to get the selected row field 'name' data.
How do I do it?
I have tried 'selections.data.name' and 'selections.get('name')' but none works.
I know it's possible because Firebug shows the data of the variable 'selections'.

Comment: `selections` is an array of records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is:
**selections[0].data.name** or **selections[0].get('name')**